# Why is an NSArrayController allowing removal of objects when there's no NSTableView selection?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I have a Core Data app I'm building for OS X. My xib file has an `NSArrayController` that is bound to the `AppDelegate`'s managed object context. The `NSTableView` in the window is bound to the array controller's `arrangedObjects`. The individual columns are bound to the appropriate properties of the array controller's entity, and almost everything is working fine. Except that there's a button on the layout for removing objects which works even when there's no object selected.

It's target is the array controller's `remove:` action and its `Enabled` binding is set to the array controller's `canRemove` key.

My guess is that there's some configuration of the array controller that I need to set so that it disallows removal of objects unless there's a selection, but I can't seem to find it.

What do I have to do to make is so that the array controller won't allow an object to be removed unless there's a selection in the table view?

Comment: Answered Below regarding the configuration change

Comment: Perhaps a clue. The remove button doesn't act on the selection when there is one. I can use the add button to create a couple of records, select one of them, click the remove button, and it seems to remove the most recently added record rather than the selected record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in addition to the bindings I mentioned, the `NSTableView` also needs to be bound. Binding its Selection Indexes to the `Array Controller.selectionIndexes` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is addition thing you need to do in the configuration.
You need to bind the button to Enable property - > Array Controller -> Selection - > Model Keypath -> "@count"..
Below is the image which will help you to fix this issue.

Buttons binding on selection is shown in the image below[image]

Comment: I had come across and attempted that solution after Googling, but it doesn't work either. This is why I think my configuration of the array controller, or the table view, must be off somehow.